# Fire c# codebind from html button

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables, code-behind

I am using Jquery DataTables, with the data being loaded using ajax and c#. For one of the tables, I need to fire off a event, which triggers generating a report using ASP.NET report viewer.

The problem I have, is getting around the button to fire the method in the code behind page.

Using the ColumnDefs option, in JQuery DataTables, I render the following which creates the button:

```
 {
    "targets": 9,
    "data": "download link",
    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<button id="btnViewReport" type="button" class="remove" runat="server" value="' + data.Id + '">View Report</button>';
    }
}
```

This shows up in my table fine, but now I need the click event to fire off the report. I was under the impression, that adding runat="server" would work, but alas no joy.

First and foremost, is it possible to add a button using JQuery, which calls a none static method?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot return via javascript a server side control. I don't know if you want this, but you could use ajax to hit a specific WebMethod on your Codebehind.

Comment: I can call a WebMethod fine, but you cant then use the asp.net report viewer in a static method, which the WebMethods have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "runat server". You need to create an html button (Like this `<button id="myid" class="myclass" ></button>`), and make one function with jQuery,then you can call your method with  QueryString or an Ajax call!

Comment: Hi Federico, doesnt this just recreate the same problem? If I call a WebMethod from Ajax using c# then the WebMethods have to be static.